# Can we mock the function that calls std::thread function using Google Test/Gmock in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, googlemock, stdthread

Can I mock the function that calls std::thread function.

e.g.
Creating thread:

```
std::thread thread_id

void myfun()
{
thread_id = std::thread(&threadfunction, this);
logger_.Info(LOG001, "Myfun() is called");
}
```

Joining a thread in another function

```
void final()
{
    if (thread_id.joinable())
      thread_id.join();
}
```

in test part:

```
TEST_F(mytest, myfun)
{
EXPECT_CALL(logger_mock_, Info(LOG001, ::testing::_)); //logging expect call
my_class_.myfun();  //my_class_ is instance object.
}
```

I want to test this function but I am getting errors "terminate called without an active exception."
That means the thread is created and became out of scope and testing is terminated. :(

Is it possible to use std::thread in gmock?

I also read that pthread is used in multi-threading Google test from documentation at:

https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/google/googletest/+/refs/tags/release-1.8.0/googletest#multi-threaded-tests

Please help with this.

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem with setting expect calls on a mock that is used in a separate thread. Your problem with `terminate called without an active exception.` is that you've created a thread that is never joined. Try:

```
void myfun()
{
    auto t = std::thread(&threadfunction, this);
    logger_.Info(LOG001, "Myfun() is called");
    t.join();
}
```

But be aware that `logger_.Info(LOG001, "Myfun() is called");` will be executed in the same thread in which `myfun` is called (i.e. in the main thread of the test app in your example). In order to `logger_.Info` to be called in thread `t`, it must be moved to `threadfunction`.

Comment: Edited the question. I have thread join but in another function. Therefore can not add t.join() in same function.

Comment: What is `threadfunction` doing? It's hard to help without whole picture. Can you create reprex (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?